# tableView.addGestureRecognizer for one section of the tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm new to iOS, swift. I have two sections in my tableView. I want to be able to do a longPressGesture on the second section, and not the first, enabling the user to reorder tableview cells in the second section. How would I do that in swift? Would anyone kindly provide a simple sample code in Swift?

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: You want gestureRecognizer on second section only or cells of second section?

Comment: @ArunGupta Hi, all cells of second section, not specific cells. Basically everything in the second section.

Comment: Add the pan gesturere recogniser to your viewcontroller, and do a hitcheck to test if the correct view (all cells in the second section) has been long pressed.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans I'm sorry I'm new but if you don't mind, could you show me an example code of adding that? Currently in my viewDidLoad i added: `let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeScreenTableViewController.longPressGestureRecognized(_:)))
        
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)` But this adds the gesture to both the first and second section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to reorder move the cell for the particular  you may add some button/action to enable/disable reorder , there is delegate which you can use

Your code can be like this:

```
//enable editing in the tableview to true when you want to enable reorder in your case may on the UILongPressGestureRecognizer action
//In viewDidLoad()
tblView.editing = true//set it to false to complete the reorder
```

The delegate methods can be use like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //get the reorder change in the path, you can do operation on the array 
    let itemToMove:String = arrData[fromIndexPath.row]//get the old path of item
    arrData.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)//remove item from old path
    arrData.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)//at item at new path in array
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
```

//write code to allow reorder in the particular section/indexpath
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    }

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {
    //check if the reorder is allow in the particular section/indexpath before the reorder is done, return the old path if you don't want to move at Proposed path
    if sourceIndexPath.section != proposedDestinationIndexPath.section {
        return sourceIndexPath
    } else {
        return proposedDestinationIndexPath
    }
}
```

---

the UILongPressGestureRecognizer can be implemented on the tableview or the tableview cell based on the requirements

```
let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(HomeScreenTableViewController.longPressGestureRecognized))
tblView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)

func longPressGestureRecognized() {
    NSLog("Detected")
    tblView.editing = true
}
```

or in tableview cell with same method as above

```
let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(HomeScreenTableViewController.longPressGestureRecognized))
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
```