# UITableViewController re-ordering of copied array?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm using a single UITableViewController to display various lists in my app.

The problem is, sometimes I want to let the user re-order the passed-in list. And because Swift passes arrays by value, any re-ordering that I do on the array in my UITableViewController obviously doesn't affect the source model. And I want it to.

I can think of some gross ways to do this, but what is the -right- way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you reordering of the list on your table? If you have function call before and after maybe record the indices and then reorder your source array manually. removeAtIndex, insertAtIndex etc

Comment: It should be based on your reorder implementation if you use insert/update/moveRowAtIndexPath  you can change the model at that time, Please specify the implementation of the reordering

Comment: you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36826731/4557505 , tableview has 'moveRowAtIndexPath ' method at where you can get the index and update your model/array based on the reorder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this counts as a gross solution, but you can use an [in-out parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545) parameter to do something like:

```
func modifyArray(inout a:Array<String>) {
    a.sortInPlace()
}

var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
modifyArray(&array)     // array is now ["five", "four", "one", "three", "two"]
```